# Команда "apt upgrade" обновляет major-версии установленных пакетов?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

Т.е. может ли она привести к конфликту программного обеспечения? Спасибо.

Comment: Ну вообще-то она сама конфликты и отслеживает и решает

Answer (score 1):

> Upgrade will attempt to gently upgrade the whole system. Upgrade will
>   never install a new package or remove an existing package, nor will it
>   ever upgrade a package that might cause some other package to break.
>   This can be used daily to relatively safely upgrade the system.
>   Upgrade will list all of the packages that it could not upgrade, this
>   usually means that they depend on new packages or conflict with some
>   other package. `dselect` or `apt-get install` can be used to force these
>   packages to install. [Source](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-guide/ch2.en.html)

Upgrade будет пытаться осторожно обновить всю систему. Upgrade никогда не будет устанавливать новый пакет или удалять существующий пакет, а также никогда не будет обновлять пакет, который может вызвать поломку другого пакета. Это можно использовать ежедневно для относительно безопасного обновления системы. Upgrade перечислит все пакеты, которые она не может обновить, обычно это означает, что они зависят от новых пакетов или конфликтуют с каким-либо другим пакетом. `dselect` или `apt-get install` можно использовать для принудительной установки этих пакетов.